# How to run a shell command with parameters and credentials in jenkins?

Tags: jenkins

This is my Jenkinsfile:

```
pipeline {
    ...
    parameters {
        string(name: 'BACKEND_VERSION', defaultValue: 'latest')
        string(name: 'FRONTEND_VERSION', defaultValue: 'latest')
    }
    environment {
        POSTGRES_PASSWORD = credentials('postgres-password')
    }
    ...
    stages {
        stage('Production Deployment') {
            steps {
                ...
                sh('./terraform apply -var postgres_password=$POSTGRES_PASSWORD -var backend_version=${params.BACKEND_VERSION} -var frontend_version=${params.FRONTEND_VERSION} --auto-approve')
                ...

            }
        }
    }
}
```

This line:

```
sh('./terraform apply -var postgres_password=$POSTGRES_PASSWORD -var backend_version=${params.BACKEND_VERSION} -var frontend_version=${params.FRONTEND_VERSION} --auto-approve')
```

produces this error:

```
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/.../script.sh: line 1: syntax error: bad substitution
```

Using double quotes (`sh("./terraform apply ...")`) produces this error:

```
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/.../script.sh: line 1: syntax error: unterminated quoted string
```

What's the correct way of string interpolation when we have both environment variables and credentials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if it's the best way or not. But I created two new environment variables from parameters:

```
environment {
    POSTGRES_PASSWORD = credentials('postgres-password')
    BACKEND_VERSION = "${params.BACKEND_VERSION}"
    FRONTEND_VERSION = "${params.FRONTEND_VERSION}"
}
```

and then use them like this:

```
sh('./terraform apply -var postgres_password=$POSTGRES_PASSWORD -var backend_version=$BACKEND_VERSION -var frontend_version=$FRONTEND_VERSION --auto-approve')
```